# Suppress password in shell script debug mode

Tags: shell, ksh

Is there any way to print an arbitrary string (like 'xxxx' or '***') in place of a password when using shell debug mode.

**Context** -
I have few scripts which connects to PostgreSQL database. We have defined the password in another hidden and protected file and then we use that file to export PGPASSWORD in the scripts so that we don't have to pass the passwords as explicit arguments.
Few users (non-DBA) have execute permission to the scripts. If they run the script using debug mode (sh -x) they will be able to see the passwords in plain text.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what OS are you using that even supports scripts having only the 'execute' permission but not 'read'? Or do you use some other way to prevent `cat $(which myscript)`?

Comment: @grawity - I've been wondering too how he hides a file which he can access from a script: maybe `setuid` could achieve this? Anyone able to read the script can see how the password is extracted from the hidden file: you don't need to run in debug mode.

Comment: @AFH: At least Linux does not support setuid scripts. And even if the script was setuid, running it indirectly via `sh -x` would only apply the privileges of `sh`, not of the script itself.

Comment: @grawity - I've just tested running a script with the `setuid` bit and confirm that it can't be used: if called normally it runs a subshell with the caller's privileges; if called with`.` it does not change the shell's user. I was only guessing before, so thanks for putting me right.